# Floated element dropping below another floated element

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am wondering why the `main` article is dropping below `sidebar1`, and why `sidebar2` is coming up next to `sidebar1`.

The `main` article is floated to the left and has no width.

How is there not enough space for it to be up next to `sidebar1`?

An explanation of the reason would greatly help.

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sidebar1 {
  background-color: cyan;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
}
.main {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
}
.sidebar2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentWrapper">
  <!-- first sidebar goes here -->
  <aside class="sidebar1">
    <h2>Sidebar 1</h2>
    <p>Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus
      elit risus id tortor.</p>
    <h3>Secondary Header</h3>
    <p>Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum.</p>
    <h3>Secondary Header</h3>
    <p>Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum.</p>
  </aside>
  <!-- main content goes here -->
  <article class="main">
    <h2>Article Title</h2>
    <p>Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus
      elit risus id tortor. Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum.</p>
    <p>Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus elit risus id tortor.</p>
    <p>Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus
      elit risus id tortor. Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum.</p>
    <h3>Subheading</h3>
    <p>Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus
      elit risus id tortor. Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum.</p>
    <h3>Subheading</h3>
    <p>Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus
      elit risus id tortor. Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra
      mi, vel faucibus elit risus id tortor. Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet,
      nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus elit risus id tortor. Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet
      luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus elit risus id tor</p>
  </article>
  <!-- second sidebar goes here -->
  <aside class="sidebar2">
    <h2>Sidebar 2 </h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Aenean orci ante</li>
      <li>Venenatis non adipiscing vita</li>
      <li>Fringilla et neque</li>
      <li>Aenean orci ante</li>
      <li>Venenatis non adipiscing vita</li>
      <li>Fringilla et neque</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus
      elit risus id tortor.Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit.</p>
    <p>Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus elit risus id tortor.Suspendisse vitae quam lorem,
      in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus elit risus id tortor.</p>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a few things here:

1. Set width of `content` to 80% (as you set `sidebar1` with 20%) because otherwise the width of the floated box will be determined by its contents, and then
2. clear the float after the `content` with:

   ```
   <div style="clear:both"></div>
   ```

and there you go!

```css
* {
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.sidebar1 {
 background-color: cyan;
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
}

.main {
 background-color: green;
 float: left;
    width: 80%;
}

.sidebar2 {
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentWrapper">
  <!-- first sidebar goes here -->
  <aside class="sidebar1">
   <h2>Sidebar 1</h2>
   <p>Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus elit risus id tortor.  </p>
     <h3>Secondary Header</h3>
     <p>Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum.  </p>
     <h3>Secondary Header</h3>
     <p>Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. </p>
  </aside>
  <!-- main content goes here -->
  <article class="main">
   <h2>Article Title</h2>
   <p>Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus elit risus id tortor. Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum.</p>
    <p>Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus elit risus id tortor. </p>
    <p>Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus elit risus id tortor. Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. </p>
     <h3>Subheading</h3>
    <p>Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus elit risus id tortor. Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. </p>
    <h3>Subheading</h3>
    <p>Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus elit risus id tortor. Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus elit risus id tortor. Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus elit risus id tortor. Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus elit risus id tor</p>
  </article>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <!-- second sidebar goes here -->
  <aside class="sidebar2">
   <h2>Sidebar 2 </h2>
   <ul>
       <li>Aenean orci ante</li>
       <li>Venenatis non adipiscing vita</li>
       <li> Fringilla et neque</li>
       <li>Aenean orci ante</li>
       <li>Venenatis non adipiscing vita</li>
       <li> Fringilla et neque</li>
     </ul>
     <p>Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus elit risus id tortor.Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. </p>
     <p>Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus elit risus id tortor.Suspendisse vitae quam lorem, in tempus velit. Sed vitae ante quis felis fringilla condimentum. Aenean orci ante, venenatis non adipiscing vitae, fringilla et neque. In pharetra, eros imperdiet luctus imperdiet, nunc sem pharetra mi, vel faucibus elit risus id tortor.</p>
  </aside>
 </div>
```

Comment: Any clarification on why the text doesn't just fill up the 80% width remaining within the first section?

Comment: it won't as if you don't set the width of a floated container, its contents will determine the width...

Comment: @kukkuz would you care to explain the reason for the float drop?

Comment: @RobertRocha think I've already done that? please point me out if I have missed something?

Comment: @RobertRocha try adding `float: left` to `sidebar2` without clearing `float` as it is done above and see the effect... the point is the `width` of a floated container and the `clear`ing of floats... hope you get my point

Comment: @kukkuz i figured it out using the `inspect element`. Basically when you float something and it doesn't have a width the width is assumed to be 100% or the entire width of its contents.

Comment: of course, that's what I told about the contents of the floated box determine the width and take it to 100% here

Answer (score 1):

There's a big hint for the answer in your question.

*You wrote:*

> The `main` article is floated to the left and has no width.

Well, you should *always* set a width on a floated element.

> The box being floated should have a width defined for it,
>   either explicitly or implicitly. Otherwise, it will fill its
>   containing block horizontally, just like non-floated content, leaving
>   no room for other content to flow around it.
>
> <sub>source:
>   http://www.brainjar.com/css/positioning/default3.asp</sub>

---

> You should always set a width on floated items (except if applied
>   directly to an image – which has implicit width). If no width is set,
>   the results can be unpredictable.
>
> <sub>source:
>   http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/introduction.htm</sub>

---

Additional references:

- [CSS Float Theory: Things You Should Know](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/) ~ Smashing Magazine
- [9.5 Floats](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#floats) ~ W3C

Comment: Thanks for the quality answer!